# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bcolz'

Tags: python, module, jupyter

I'm working in the Jupyter Notebook inside a Conda environment.
I've installed `bcolz` about three different ways but I always get the below screenshot on my notebook page.
When I'm in the environment and type 'Python' or 'Python3' (in other words, go into Python) I can import the module with no problem when typing the same command being given to Jupyter `import bcolz`.

Specifically, I installed by typing...

```
conda install -c anaconda bcolz  
pip3 install bcolz  
conda install -c conda-forge bcolz
```

and I think I also installed it within some other bundle of modules
*I did a restart to the computer a few times as well.

**UPDATE:** I just took the `import cbolz` line out of the `utils.py` file the notebook was loading and put `import cbolz` into that cell instead.
Works now, didn't think of doing before. Am still interested in why it doesn't work in the first way.

[image: My Jupyter Notebook Error Screenshot]

Comment: Is the kernel you are using in your jupyter notebook the conda environment in which the `bcolz` module is installed ?
Because, on my computer, even when I launch the notebook inside a conda environment, the default kernel is always `Python 3` and not the conda environment.

Comment: Tried Python 2 and Python 3 under Kernal > Change Kernal after reading your comment. It gives the same ModuleNotFoundError as above. Also, idk if what you were asking but I start the Notebook from the dir and activated conda env. I guess it's just a bug putting it in the cell instead of the script fixed.

Comment: Sigh. After this fix of putting that one 'import' line into the cell I'm running into the same problem with other scripts also not being able import other modules. Most modules load from the .py scripts fine. Some do not. Trying to import a ton of things from Keras and other scripts that try to make use of modules. It's making these fast.ai Jupyter Notebooks unusable.

Comment: I had the same problems with fastai. Some of these problems can be solved if you pay a VERY careful attention to the versions of the libraries used. For example, Keras' version is 1 whereas the newest version installed by pip is Keras 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not running your jupyter notebook with the kernel associated with your conda environment. Here is how to do it:

```
$ source activate my_conda_env
(my_conda_env) $ conda install nb_conda
```

Then, relaunch the jupyter notebook, and you will normally see `my_conda_env` in the kernel list. Select it and run this in a cell in your notebook:

```
import bcolz
```

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense. Maybe you'll know this one too. Why when I want to install one single module in the environment and enter 'conda install -c anaconda pil' so many other modules get installed? 4 modules + Tensorflow being installed now just from entering that one line. EDIT: Now 15 other packages loading.

Comment: These are the dependencies of the library, that is to say the libraries the library you are installing needs. It's totally normal, without them, the library you are installing would not work.

Comment: But if I were you, I would install my packages with pip, even in an anaconda environment. That's what I do and it works perfectly

Comment: Ok. I prefer pip and virtualenv. Didn't know I could use pip in Conda. Just using Conda for the fast.ai course. The guy says Conda is better. Seems slow and big.

Comment: Just tried a side by side Sklearn pip install next to an Sklearn conda install. Pip installed Sklearn with 12MB and conda is still going like every time installing 
scikit-learn 0.19.1: 
icu 54.1: 
certifi 2017.11.5:
openssl 1.0.2n: 
subprocess32 3.2.7: 
scipy 1.0.0: 
libgcc 7.2.0:
matplotlib 2.0.2: 
pyqt 5.6.0: 
ca-certificates 2017.08.26: tensorflow 1.1.0: 
numexpr 2.6.4: 
libxml2 2.9.4: 
numpy 1.12.1:

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the module is even present in your system.

```
pip freeze | grep bcolz
```

or

```
conda list | grep bcolz
```

If both the commands return nil, you know you don't have this module installed. So, go ahead and install it by running

```
conda install -c anaconda bcolz
```